# RegEx to find and remove event attributes ex. onclick, onload, onhover etc

Tags: php, regex

I have been at this on and off for a few days, but my RexEx mastery is not great.  Yes I understand that RegEx is not for parsing HTML.  I am doing server side "cleaning" of CKEditor input, which already does this, but only client side.

After striping none white-listed tags...

First: `$html = preg_replace(' on\w+=(["\'])[^\1]*?\1', '', $html);` *remove all event attributes properly quoted with either `'` or `"` quotes*

Second: `$html = preg_replace(' on\w+=\S+', '', $html);` *remove the ones that have no quotes but still can fire, ex. onclick=blowUpTheBase()

What I would like to do is ensure the onEvent is between `<` & `>` but I can only get it to work if the onEvent attribute is the first one after a tag.  Everything I try ends up capturing most of the code.  I just cant get it lazy enough.

ex. `$html = preg_replace('<([\s\S]?)( on\w+=\S+) ([\s\S]*?)>', '<$1 $3>', $html);`

EDIT:
I am going to select @colburton's answer because RegEx is what I asked for.  I will also use it for my particular situation because it will due the trick. (it is an internal application anyhow)

BUT

I want to thank @Casimir et Hippolyte for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112209/3790921) because it gives a great example and explanation about how to do this the **"right way"**.  I will in short order write up a function using DOMDocument and it will become my goto way of handling RTE/WYSIWYG/HTML input.

Comment: The `[^\1]` does not work as you think it  does. You need to use `(?:(?!\1).)*` instead. Besides, you should use regex delimiters.

Comment: Quotes problems and attributes position are two of the many reasons why parsing your html with regex is a bad idea. These problems don't exist when you use DOMDocument. Enclose your html content inside a fake root element, let's say '<div>....</div>` and use this build in parser.

Comment: Note also that you can't trust in external data, so if there's already a part of the cleaning that is supposed to be done on client side, you must do it one more time on server side or at least to check it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte DOMDocument, quite the class. I am interested in learning the proper way to parse HTML and clean it, got any links to examples?  P.S. I am server side checking it, that's what this question is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I should have mentioned this from the start: This is not how you should try to filter XSS. This is purely academic inside the parameters you proposed (eg. "use RegEx").

---

This gets you pretty close:

```
preg_replace('/(<.+?)(?<=\s)on[a-z]+\s*=\s*(?:([\'"])(?!\2).+?\2|(?:\S+?\(.*?\)(?=[\s>])))(.*?>)/ig', "$1 $3", $string);
```

Tested on

```
<a href="something" onclick="bad()">text</a> onclick not in tags
<a href="something" onclick=bad()>text</a>
<a href="something" onclick="bad()" >text</a>
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">

<a href="something" onclick= "bad()">text</a> onclick not in tags
<a href="something" onclick =bad()>text</a>
<a href="something" onclick=bad('test')>text</a>
<a href="something" onclick=bad("test")>text</a>
<a href="something" onclick="bad()" >text</a>
What if I write john+onelia=love forever?
```

Play around here:
https://regex101.com/r/GMBaQs/9

Comment: Several counter examples: https://regex101.com/r/GMBaQs/2

Comment: @Casimir: Thx for the input. Let's go another round ;-)

Comment: it's pushing it, but, https://regex101.com/r/GMBaQs/5 gets one through.  Thanks for the Answer so far, puts me to shame.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/GMBaQs/8